# Class issues, __init__ arguments not matching

Tags: python, class

Ok so I have been hunting around for awhile, please excuse the fact that this is probably a fairly simple question, but no matter how many threads I read of the same error type, I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am missing something conceptually I believe.

Here is the code:

```
class Song(object):

    def __init__ (self, lyrics, feliz):
        self.lyrics = lyrics
        self.feliz = "feliz navidad, etc etc"

    def sing_me_a_song(self):
        for line in self.lyrics:
            print line

happy_bday = Song(["\n\nHappy birthday to you",
                "I don't want to get sued",
                "So I'll stop right there.\n\n\n"])

bulls_on_parade = Song(["They rally around the family",
                    "With pockets full of shells.\n"])

happy_bday.sing_me_a_song()

bulls_on_parade.sing_me_a_song()

songz = Song()
print songz.feliz()
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex40.py", line 13, in <module>
    "So I'll stop right there.\n\n\n"])
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

I realize this is probably dumb, but I am hung up on this and would really like some help. If it means anything this is obviously from LPTHW and I have editted lesson 40, the code words fine if i remove all the references to feliz, that was me trying to add my own variable to the class Song and then have it print out at the end. Thank you in advance.

---

So I can make it do what I want by adding the following:

```
feliz_navidad = Song(["Feliz navidad",
                    "Feliz navidad",
                    "Prospero anos delicidad.\n"])

feliz_navidad.sing_me_a_song()
```

But, is there no other way for me to use the class to have it print a string than to use the defined sing_me_a_song function?

***I was attempting to reference the Song class and have it print out a string without using a function defined inside... I suppose that is a dumb thing to do.*** I misunderstood how it works...

Comment: Your `__init__` method asks for two arguments (`self` is passed implicitly), but you only give it one. You never use `feliz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined your `__init__` function to accept two arguments, `lyrics` and `feliz`.  You only passed one argument, which appears to be `lyrics`.

It's not clear from your question what you want your code to do.  If you only want to pass one argument, just remove `feliz` from the argument list of your `__init__`, so it's just `def __init__(self, lyrics)`.  Right now, you aren't using the `feliz` argument at all, so it doesn't seem to have any purpose.

I also suggest you read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) to get a grasp of the basics of Python.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
happy_bday = Song(["\n\nHappy birthday to you",
            "I don't want to get sued",
            "So I'll stop right there.\n\n\n"])
```

You are passing a `list[...]`, that is 1 paramter. The exception says *2 given*, because `self` is passed implictly as parameter. But the `__init__` method you declared expects `3`:

- `self`
- `lyrics`
- `feliz`

I would recommend you to delete `feliz` parameter, because don't matter what you pass as argument, you are just assigning `feliz` a string `"feliz navidad, etc etc"`

```
def __init__ (self, lyrics):
```

Comment: Lyrics is intended to be a list. Look at his code for sing_me_a_song